# Bootstrap WordPress - PHP loop wrong order of colums per row

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have Website with WordPress Bootstrap:

```
http://www.obra-93.hr/zavrseni-projekti/
```

I have portfolio with items per row.
The code for loop 3 items per row (totaly 20 items) is below:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row vrow">
<?php // slideshow
$args_projekti = array(
    'showposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'post_type' => 'projekti',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'cache_results' => false,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false
);
$projekti = new wp_query($args_projekti);
$p=0;
if ($projekti->have_posts()):
?>

    <?php
    while ($projekti->have_posts()): 
        $projekti->the_post();
            $post_id  = get_the_ID();
    ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('projekt-thumb', array('class' => 'img-responsive fade center-block'));?></a>
            <h3 class="text-center"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        </div>
         <?php if($p%3===0){echo '</div><div class="row vrow">';} ?>
    <?php $p++; endwhile;  endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

My first and last row is not working properly. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Changed if($p%3===0) to if($p%3===1) - better, but is this soluton?

Comment: You probably want `(($p+1) % 3 === 0)`

Comment: Or just set your `$p = 1;` ;) Also there are a lot of similar answers and questions out there. [For instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787431/wrapping-every-3-elements-in-a-loop-leaves-an-empty-wrapper/)

Comment: Sure, got it working! Thank You both for ideas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you increment $p after the if condition the values would be like

0,1,2
3,4,5
and so on an because 0 % 3 == 0
so you could start p with 1 then it looks like
1,2,3
4,5,6
or increment before the check

Comment: Ohh, I get it now! Tried and it is working. Thanks for detailed explanation :)